# Web2py product review site. How to show results from referenced database?

Tags: web2py

I am developing a product review site. I am struggling to show all reviews related to the product.

What I really want is a WHERE clause that allows me to say where products.id = reviews.prodId... and show all results but from what i have seen this is the way to do it.

When a review is made, the product id is entered. The reviews are stored in the reviews database which has a reference value to the products database although i am not sure if it is correct:

```
db.define_table('reviews',
            Field('id',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()), #auto number
            Field('prodId',db.products.id,requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()), #referenced id
            Field('title',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()), # title of the review
            Field('body', 'text',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()), # review
            Field('time_stamp','datetime'),  # timestamp w/date
            primarykey=['id'],
            migrate=False)
```

default.py:

```
def show():
reviews = db.reviews(request.args(0)) 
products = db.products(request.args(0)) 
return locals()
```

show.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{for row in db(db.reviews.prodId == 1).select():}}
<h2>
 {{=reviews.title}} for {{=products.name}}
 </h2>
 <i>Posted on {{=reviews.time_stamp}} by (persons name)</i>
 <p>
 <b>
 {{=reviews.body}}
 </b>
 </p>
 {{pass}}
```

Thanks, Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [recursive select](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Recursive-selects), you can do:

```
def show():
    product = db.products(request.args(0))
    reviews = product.reviews.select()
    return locals()
```

Above, `product.reviews.select()` is equivalent to `db(db.reviews.prodId == product.id).select()`.

In the view, you would then have:

```
{{for review in reviews:}}
<h2>{{=review.title}} for {{=product.name}}</h2>
 <i>Posted on {{=review.time_stamp}} by (persons name)</i>
 <p>
 <b>
 {{=review.body}}
 </b>
 </p>
{{pass}}
```

Another option would be to do a [join](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Inner-joins):

```
def show():
    rows = db((db.products.id == request.args(0)) &
              (db.reviews.prodId == db.products.id)).select()
    return locals()
```

Then in the view:

```
{{for row in rows:}}
<h2>{{=row.reviews.title}} for {{=row.products.name}}</h2>
 <i>Posted on {{=row.reviews.time_stamp}} by (persons name)</i>
 <p>
 <b>
 {{=row.reviews.body}}
 </b>
 </p>
{{pass}}
```